# How can I use sklearn CountVectorizer with mutliple strings?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a list of strings (10,000s). Some of the strings constitute multiple words. I have another list which contains some sentences. I am trying to do a count of the number of times each string in my list appears in each sentence.

At present I am using sklearn's feature extraction tool, because it works very quickly when we have 10,000s of strings to look up and 10,000s of sentences.

Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_extraction

sentences = ["hi brown cow", "red ants", "fierce fish"]

listOfStrings = ["brown cow", "ants", "fish"]

cv = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=listOfStrings)
taggedSentences = cv.fit_transform(sentences).toarray()

taggedSentencesCutDown = taggedSentences > 0
# Here we get an array of tuples <sentenceIndex, stringIndexfromStringList>
taggedSentencesCutDown = np.column_stack(np.where(taggedSentencesCutDown))
```

at the moment, if you run this the output is the following:

```
In [2]: taggedSentencesCutDown
Out[2]: array([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
```

what I want is:

```
In [2]: taggedSentencesCutDown
Out[2]: array([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
```

My current use of CountVectorizer shows that it is not looking for multiple word strings. Is there someway else to do this without going into long for loops. Efficiency and time are quite important for my app as my lists are in the 10,000s.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the parameter `analyzer`. I don't think it is possible right know to do what you want with sklearn's `CountVectorizer`, as it only supports words or n-grams of chars, not multiple of words. You could override this by passing your own `callable` function, but for each sentence you would have to return not only the words, but all the combinations between them. Unless you are a bit more specific with your constrains on the size or amount of words in your `listOfStrings` the problem wont be quick to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this by playing with the n-grams parameter in the CountVectorizer.

If I am able to find the largest number of words a single string in my wordlist I can set this as the upper limit to my n-gram. In the example above it is "brown cow" with two.

```
cv = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=listOfStrings,
       ngram_range=(1, 2))
```