# Using Sklearn's CountVectorizer to find multiple strings not in order

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

Can the CountVectorizer be used to identify if a set of words appear in the corpus regardless of order?

It can do ordered phrases: [How can I use sklearn CountVectorizer with mutliple strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108834/how-can-i-use-sklearn-countvectorizer-with-mutliple-strings)

Yet for my case the set of words do not happen to fall next to each over so tokenizing the whole phrase and then trying to find in some text document will result in zero finds

What I dream is for the following to happen:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_extraction

sentences = [ "The only cool Washington is DC", 
              "A cool city in Washington is Seattle",
              "Moses Lake is the dirtiest water in Washington" ]

listOfStrings = ["Washington DC",
                 "Washington Seattle",  
                 "Washington cool"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=listOfStrings)
bagowords = np.matrix(vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences).todense())
bagowords
matrix([[1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],])
```

The actual problem entails more words in between and thus removing stop words here would not be a valid solution. Any advice would be awesome!

Comment: Since you say "regardless of order", will it still be a valid match, if the sentence contains "DC stands for District of Columbia in Washington"? Here DC is many words before Washington.

Comment: Yes that would still be a valid match!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, since you only want to find out certain words are present in the document or not, then you will need to change the vocabulary (`listOfStrings`) a little bit.

```
sentences = [ "The only cool Washington is DC", 
              "A cool city in Washington is Seattle",
              "Moses Lake is the dirtiest water in Washington" ]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
listOfStrings = ["washington", "dc", "seattle", "cool"]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=listOfStrings,
                             binary=True)   

bagowords = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences).toarray()

vectorizer.vocabulary
['washington', 'dc', 'seattle', 'cool']

bagowords
array([[1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I have added `binary=True` to the CountVectorizer since you dont want the actual counts, only check if word is present or not.

The output of `bagowords` matches the order of vocabulary (`listOfStrings`) you supplied. So the first column represents if "washinton" is present in documents or not, second column checks for "dc" and so on.

Of course you will need to give attention to other parameters in CountVectorizer which can affect this. For example:,

- `lowercase` is `True` by default, so I used lowercase words in `listOfStrings`. Otherwise, "DC", "Dc", "dc" are considered as separate words.
- You should also study about the effect of `token_pattern` param which by default only keeps alphanumeric strings of length 2 or more. So if you want to detect a single letter words like "a", "I" etc, then you will need to change that.

Hope this helps. If not understand anything, feel free to ask.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but my goal here was to find if the list of key terms appears in the corpus as a whole, not individually. I like the use of binary=True. I was doing this by hand before. But the way this is set up I do not know if Seattle and Washington occur in a particular sentence. Of course with this example I could compute this, but with a larger example I would not be able to match up the list of key terms. Any thoughts on how I can search a list of key words that do not appear next to each other, and have a return of 1 or 0 based on if all of these words occur?